awk: split logfile, starting from 1st line matching minimum value up until last line before maximum value is exceeded
I have a logfile from a service which was never rotated. Now I want to split this logfile into separate files, one for each month.
Most lines start with the unix-timestamp enclosed in brackets, however there are log-messages spanning multiple lines (output from dig) which needs to be grabbed to.
Additionally the next line with a timestamp after a multi-line message is not necessarily from the same month. Like in the example below.
1700653509 = Wed 22 Nov 12:45:09 CET 2023
1700798246 = Fri 24 Nov 04:57:26 CET 2023
1701385200 = Fri  1 Dec 00:00:00 CET 2023

[1700653509] unbound[499:0] debug: module config: "subnetcache validator iterator"
[1700798246] unbound[1506:0] info: incoming scrubbed packet: ;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, rcode: NOERROR, id: 0
;; flags: qr aa ; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0
;; QUESTION SECTION:
chat.cdn.whatsapp.net.  IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
chat.cdn.whatsapp.net.  60      IN      A       157.240.252.61

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 55

[1701385200] unbound[1506:0] debug: iter_handle processing q with state QUERY RESPONSE STATE

My first approach was to define minimum and maximum values (1st and last second of a month) and check if the timestamp in the line matches that range. If yes, write it to the new logfile and move on.
I need this approach as not every first or last second of a month is present in the logfile.
Like this:
for YEAR in {2023..2024}; do
  for MONTH in {1..12}; do

# Calculate first and last second of each month
FIRST_SECOND="$(date -d "$(date +"$YEAR"/"$MONTH"/01)" "+%s")"
LAST_SECOND="$(date -d "$(date +"$YEAR"/"$MONTH"/01) + 1 month - 1 second" "+%s")"`

awk -F'[\\[\\]]' -v MIN="${FIRST_SECOND}" -v MAX="${LAST_SECOND}" '{if($2 >= MIN && $2 <= MAX) print}' unbound.log >> "unbound-$YEAR-$MONTH.log
  done;
done

Then I encountered the multi-line messages and hit a roadblock.
Basically what I need now is some kind of "Grab all matching and non-matching lines until you hit the first value bigger then MAX."
I thought of getting the first and last matching line number and simply use those. But then again I have the same problem with the multi-line messages.
Any ideas?
EDIT: Based on the accepted answer I ended up with this. I changed the filename to unbound-YYYY-MM instead of MM-YYYY and also gzip each file after it has been closed.
awk '
$1 ~ /^\[[0-9]+]$/ {
  f = "unbound-" strftime("%Y-%m", substr($1, 2, length($1)-2)) ".log"
  if (f != prev) {
    if (prev) system("gzip " prev)
    close(prev)
    prev = f
  }
}
{
  print > f
}
END {
  if (prev) system("gzip " prev)
}' unbound.log


Don't use all upper case variable names in shell or awk (unless you have some in shell you need to export) to avoid clobbering builtin and environment variables, see correct-bash-and-shell-script-variable-capitalization for the shell rationale but much of it applies to awk too.

You might want to always have the month be 2 digits rather than sometimes 1 and sometimes 2 so your output files can be easily sorted.

Oh, good catch regarding the variables. Never thought about that. And yes, having the with 2 digits rather then 1 is preferrable. Luckily the answer from @RenaudPacalet already includes this.

With GNU awk (for strftime):
awk '
$1 ~ /^\[[0-9]+]$/ {
  f = "unbound-" strftime("%Y-%m", substr($1, 2, length($1)-2)) ".log"
  if (f != prev) close(f); prev = f
}
{
  print > f
}' unbound.log

For each line which first field is a [timestamp] (that is, matches regexp ^\[[0-9]+]$), we use substr and length to extract timestamp, strftime to convert it to a YYYY-mm string and assign "unbound-YYYY-mm.log" to variable f. In the second block, that applies to all lines, we print the current line in file f. Note: contrary to shell redirections, in awk, print > FILE appends to FILE.
Edit: as suggested by Ed Morton closing each file when we are done with it should significantly improve the performance if the total number of files is large. if (f != prev) close(f); prev = f  added. Ed also noted that escaping the final ] in the regex is useless (and undefined behavior per POSIX). Backslash removed.

Did a test run on a test-logfile with various entries (in sorted order) where multi-line messages appear in the middle of the month, at the start or the end. Worked flawlessly. Number of lines in each file matched exactly the numbers for each month. Even when lines didn't include a timestamp. I just added code to gzip each file after it had been closed and Changed the format to YYYY-MM instead of MM-YYYY.

Oops, sorry. I edit the answer to replace mm-YYYY with YYYY-mm.


Any ideas?

I would exploit RS built-in variable of GNU AWK following way, consider simplified example, let file.txt content be
[1700653509] one line message
[1700798246] multi
line message
[1701385200] another one line message

then
awk 'BEGIN{FPAT="[0-9]+";RS="\n\\[";}{printf("%s%s\n",NR==1?"":"[",$0)>strftime("file%Y%m.txt",$1)}' file.txt

creates file202311.txt holding
[1700653509] one line message
[1700798246] multi
line message

and file202312.txt holding
[1701385200] another one line message

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that row separator is newline followed by left square bracket and run of digits constitute fields, Then for each row I prepare what to print depending on if it is first row or no, in latter case we need to prepend left square bracket, which I then output to file which name is based at timestamp.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Thanks! This generally works. However there is file197001.txt created and it holds a line [1700653509] unbound[499:0] debug: module config: "subnetcache validator iterator" which is from Wed 22 Nov 12:45:09 CET 2023. But putting that file in front of the file202311.txt is not a big problem. :-)
